# Line element of a field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, geodesics

I recently had a question ... Is there an intuitive way to go about the line-element of field? (without going into method below).

The only way I can conceive going about this is to use Einstein field equations and start with the stress energy tensor? Also what is the line-element of say the electromagnetic field? (if it can be defined this way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In currently-accepted theories, arbitrary fields don’t have line elements. A line element is a geometrical concept, measuring spacetime separations. It is represented by only *one* field, the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$, whose theorized quanta are gravitons. Quark fields, gluon fields, electron fields, photon fields, etc. don’t *represent* spacetime geometry in standard theories. However, their energy and momentum do *determine* the metric tensor, and thus the geometry of spacetime, through the Einstein field equations.

By contrast, in some speculative theories with additional dimensions, other fields besides the metric field *can* represent the higher-dimensional geometry. In such theories, fields such as the photon field are just additional components of a $d$-dimensional metric tensor with $d>4$. Some physicists think that quantized higher-dimensional spacetime might eventually explain all fields and all interactions between fields.